# Android studio - I can't find 'libs' folder

Tags: android, android-library

I changed 'Android' to 'Project'.
But I can't find libs folder.
How can I find the 'libs' folder???
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MD09.png)

Comment: have you tried refreshing studio? try opening and closing it.

Answer (score 1):

try invalidate caches & restart

1. File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart
2. Build -> Rebuild Project
3. Run this command in terminal -> `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

1. File -> Invalidate cashes and Restart
2. Build -> Clean
3. Build -> Rebuild

Comment: I did it but I couldn't find :( How about uploading libraries in  '.idea > libraries' ??? I can see that folder.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart, worked for me